# Setting the width of a Silverlight application based on screen size

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

On a silverlight 4.0 application I need to set the width of the main window to be the maximum possible width based on the size of the screen of user.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What does your XAML look like? The default is for the Silverlight app .to fit 100% of the browser window. I assume that you mean in OOB mode? Please clarify